# Connection.Open() necessary when calling stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, database-connection

Normaly I would use either "Using" or just connection.open() and connection.close(). But when I'm calling stored procedure, this is not needed. How come? (Yes the codesnippit below works without using or open).

```
try {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("***", connectionSiteDb);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcessSegmentID", ProcessSSegmentID));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PO_RecipeID", PO_RecipeID));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductSegmentVersion", ProductSegmentVersion));


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
catch (Exception e) {
     Console.WriteLine(e);
     return null;
}
```

Comment: have you checked connection property? is connectionstate is closed?

Comment: before call stroe procedure close your connection

Comment: It's the SqlDataAdapter. It will open the connection if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) or not doesn't depends on your `CommandType` is `Text` or `StoredProcedure`.

`SqlDataAdapter.Fill` opens connection itself.

From [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> The Fill method implicitly opens the Connection that the DataAdapter
>   is using if it finds that the connection is not already open. If Fill
>   opened the connection, it will also close the connection when Fill is
>   finished. This can simplify your code when dealing with a single
>   operation such as a Fill or an Update.

Also [DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The
>   connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid,
>   **but it does not need to be open**. If the connection is closed before
>   Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the
>   connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

Since `SqlDataAdapter` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, you don't need to use using statement with it.

If you want to look under the hood, you can check [`QuietClose` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/R/555a8f558f3363ed.html) and [`QuietOpen` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/R/be415b68c2a6229a.html) implementations;

```
static private void QuietClose(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState originalState)
{
      // close the connection if:
      // * it was closed on first use and adapter has opened it, AND
      // * provider's implementation did not ask to keep this connection open
      if ((null != connection) && (ConnectionState.Closed == originalState)) {
          // we don't have to check the current connection state because
          // it is supposed to be safe to call Close multiple times
          connection.Close();
      }
}

// QuietOpen needs to appear in the try {} finally { QuietClose } block
// otherwise a possibility exists that an exception may be thrown, i.e. ThreadAbortException
// where we would Open the connection and not close it
static private void QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, out ConnectionState originalState)
{
     originalState = connection.State;
     if (ConnectionState.Closed == originalState) {
         connection.Open();
     }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks (Accepting your answer as soon as possible)